# Ĉu ekzistas vorto en Esperanto por la angla vorto "jobsworth"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Ĉu jam ekzistas vorto aŭ akceptita esprimo en Esperanto por la angla vorto *jobsworth*? (Tio ĉi signifas "laboristo, kiu rifuzas esti fleksebla rilate la regulojn de sia laboro por helpi klientojn (ŝajne pro timo perdi sian laboron).")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eble la vorto [*pedanto*](http://vortaro.net/#pedanto) estus sufiĉe proksima se oni aldonas iom da kunteksto. Ekzemple:

> Mi telefonis la bankon por peti prokrasti la limdaton de mia ŝuldo, sed respondis **pedanto** pri la reguloj kaj ri rifuzis.

Oni povus eĉ kombini tion en unu vorton:

> La **regulpedantoj** ĉe la banko neniam volas helpi min.

Comment: Mi precipe ŝatas vian sugeston de "regulpedanto"; mi pensas, ke tio ĉi esprimas pli-malpi la saman ideon kiel la angla vorto.

Answer (score 1):

Mi ankoraŭ volas mencii `burokrato`, vidu [Retan Vortaron](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/)

> **burokrato**
>   2.  ↝
>   (malŝate) Persono, kiu rigore sekvas la administrajn regulojn kaj rutinojn, sed ignoras la bazan celaron de la laboro aŭ la demokratian devon reagi al publikaj kritikoj: *la burokrataj formalaĵoj, ĉikanoj.*

Answer (score 0):

Mi vidis la artikolon "Ĉikanado" en Vikipedio (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%88ikanado). Oni eble povus paroli pri "ĉikanemulo"?

Comment: Mi pensas ke tiu vorto estus pli kiel *bullying* en la angla. Laŭ mia kompreno *jobsworth* ne vere intence agas malice, sed nur tro emas obei la regulojn eĉ kiam tio malhelpas klientojn aŭ kolegojn.